# Unable to send large payload using fetch in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I am a beginner in the JavaScript and NodeJS space. I was trying to create a simple file upload project with NodeJS. Furthermore, I created the routes in NodeJS and capturing the image from the webpage and sending it to the NodeJS routes using fetch.
This is the HTML file:

```html
<div class="file-upload">
    <div class="image-upload-wrap">
        <input class="file-upload-input" type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" accept="image/*" />
        <div class="drag-text">
        <h3>Drag and drop a file or select add Image</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="file-upload-content">
        <div class="file-upload-display">
            <img id="file-upload-image" class="file-upload-image" src="#" alt="your image" />
            <div class="image-title-wrap">
                <button type="button" onclick="removeUpload()" class="remove-image"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Remove <span class="image-title">Uploaded Image</span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="file-upload-server d-flex justify-content-center">
    <button class="btn btn-expand-lg btn-primary" onclick="uploadFile()"><i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i> Upload</button>
</div>
```

This is my JavaScript file:

```
    async function uploadFile() {
    let img = document.getElementById('file-upload-image').src;
    console.log('Image String Length: ' + img.length);
    const payload = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            file: img, 
        })
    }
    console.log(`Payload: ${JSON.stringify(payload)}`);
    
   await fetch('http://localhost:3030/image/uploadimage', payload)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log('Success:', data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}
```

The image here is the base64 encoded string and that I passing to my nodejs route.

When I click my upload button I get the following error:

[image]

I have tested this code with an image of size 5.72kb and it works. But when I try to upload an image of size 81.7kb it fails with that error.

This is the nodejs route:

```
router.use(imageupload({
   limits: { fileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024 },
}));

router.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
router.use(express.json());

const decodeBase64Image = (dataString) => {
  let matches = dataString.match(/^data:([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/),
  response = {};
  if (matches.length !== 3) {
    return new Error('Invalid input string');
  }
  response.type = matches[1];
  response.data = Buffer.from(matches[2], 'base64');
  return response;
}

router.post('/uploadimage', cors(corsOptions), async (req, res) => {
     let decodedImage = decodeBase64Image(req.body.file); 
     let imageBuffer = decodedImage.data;
     let type = decodedImage.type;
     let extension = mime.getExtension(type);
     let NewImageName =  Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
     let fileName = 'image-' + NewImageName + '.' + extension;
     try {
           fs.writeFile(`${path.join(__dirname, '../')}/public/uploads/${fileName}`, 
           imageBuffer, function(err) {
           if(err) throw err;
           console.log('The file was uploaded successfully');
           return res.status(200).json({status: 'success', message: 'File uploaded successfully'});
    });
    } catch(err) { 
          console.log(err);
          return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
});
```

Any help or guidance around this would be great.

Comment: Please provide error messages as text, not as pictures of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set an upload limit for your `express.json()` middleware since you are using `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` header in the post request.

Try replacing `router.use(express.json())` with `router.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb'})`

[Documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#express.json)

#### Edit

The error `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0'` happens if you try to parse a string with `response.json()` which is not formatted as `json`. You can reproduce it in a one liner in nodejs as `JSON.parse('I am no json...')`

If you call `response.json()` on the client , it has to be properly formatted `json` or it result in an error. For doing so, use `res.json()` instead of `res.send()`.

You should also make sure to always respond to the client, so change the line `if(err) throw err;` to

```
if(err) { 
  console.error(err)
  // always send back a status, 500 means server error.. 
  res.status(500).json('Internal server error')
  return
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @SilvanBregy, that worked. Post this, I was trying to call another api from within that node route and getting this error: invalid json response body at http://localhost:3030/image/uploadimage reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0'

Comment: await fetch('http://localhost:3030/image/uploadimage', payload)
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => {
        console.log('Success:', data);
      })
     .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
     });

Comment: @SouravMisrha-MSFT I updated my answer to fix the error.

Comment: getting some weird behavior, though what I think is when I am uploading a large file, I am getting that Unexpected token error. If I use the 5.7kb file it works fine. But when I use another bigger file of 81.7kb I started getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you should use multer here's [a link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

Backend Code Sample:

```
var multer = require('multer')
var signature = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './public/')
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    if (file.mimetype == 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png' || file.mimetype === 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet') {
        cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname)
    } else {
        cb({ error: 'Image type not supported' })
    }
}
})

var uploadSignature = multer({ storage: signature })

router.put('/updateWorkOrderForSign',uploadSignature.array('signature', 1), function (req, res) {

try {
if (req.body.signature) {
var base64Data = req.body.signature.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");

 let rString = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
 let date = Date.now();
 let imageName = '/' + date + rString + '.png';
 let imagePath = '/public' + imageName;

 require("fs").writeFile('./' + imagePath, base64Data, 'base64', function (err) {
  if (err) {
      log.error('SAVE IMAGE FAILED WITH ERROR: ', err);
   } else {
      log.info('Signature image saved successfully')
   }
  });
  } else {
          //nothing to do
          log.error("No signature image present")
  }

  } catch (err) {
          log.error('ERROR WHILE CONVERTING BASE64 TO IMAGE: ', err);
  }
})
```

Front-end code sample(I have implemented this in react native):

```
async function uploadFile() {
    let imageObject = {
              uri: image.path,
              type: 'image/png',
              name: 'signatureImage'
             }

    var form = new FormData();
        form.append('signature', imageObject)
        form.append(‘task’Id, taskId);

    await fetch(urlStr, {
                          method: 'PUT',
                          headers: {
                                  'Authorization': bearerToken,
                                   Accept: 'application/json',
                                  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
                          body: params,
                })
                  .then(response => response.json())
                  .then(responseData => {
                        var result = JSON.stringify(responseData);
                        return result;
                   })
                  .catch(error => {
                       console.log('ERROR WHILE UPLOADING IMAGE: ',error)
                  });
}
```